# CakePHP ACL with UUID primary keys

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, acl, uuid, cakephp-2.1

I am developing a CakePHP app, and I would like to use UUID as a primary keys, since the application will be distributed accross multiple databases and I would also like to take advantage of the integrated ACL framework in CakePHP 2.1

I am going according to [the tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html#preparing-our-application) and I have modified DB scheme to following

```
CREATE TABLE acos (
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  parent_id uuid DEFAULT NULL,
  model VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
  foreign_key uuid DEFAULT NULL,
  alias VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
  lft uuid DEFAULT NULL,
  rght uuid DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);

CREATE TABLE aros_acos (
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  aro_id uuid NOT NULL,
  aco_id uuid NOT NULL,
  _create CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  _read CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  _update CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  _delete CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE aros (
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  parent_id uuid DEFAULT NULL,
  model VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
  foreign_key uuid DEFAULT NULL,
  alias VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
  lft uuid DEFAULT NULL,
  rght uuid DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);
```

However now I am getting an error:

Error: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function max(uuid) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT MAX("Aro"."rght") AS "rght" FROM "public"."aros" AS "... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

The version of CakePHP is 2.1.0-beta and I'm using PostgreSQL with UUID data type.

Have anyone succesfully used CakePHP ACL framework with UUID's? I would like to get this working with minimal modification in CakePHP framework, for future supportability of this app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no aggregate function `max()` defined for the [data type `UUID`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-uuid.html). No `UUID` is considered "bigger" than another `UUID`.

Consider the following demo:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t(id uuid);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
 ('a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11')
,('b0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11');

SELECT max(id) FROM t;
```

Yields:

```
ERROR:  function max(uuid) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT max(id) FROM t;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

You can circumvent the problem. Cast the `id` to text if you want the alphabetically biggest value:

```
SELECT max(id::text) FROM t;
```

Yields:

```
b0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11
```

But be aware that that is just the standard text *representation* of a UUID. The same UUID could be represented in many other forms.

Comment: Well I know, why is it failing, but I am looking for simpliest way arround that in CakePHP ACL framework, so I do not have to create my own "sort of ACL framework". But you are right that changing types to "character(36)" makes the code go without error, though question is now, if it is still functioning.

Comment: @Marek I wouldn't change the data type. The question is, why do you need the maximum UUID? If you do, cast the value for the computation only. You could also write your own aggregate function `max(uuid)`.